# Remove venv folder from bandit scan

Tags: python, python-poetry, linter, bandit-python

When I run

```
poetry run bandit -r .
```

inside my root project's folder `root`, it consider the `.venv` path.

My folder structure is:

```
root
├── ...
├── my_package            
├── .venv                 
└── ...
```

How could I avoid this?

I've tried the `-x` parameter, but no effect was seen:

```
poetry run bandit -r . -x .venv
```

And I've also tried to insert the exclude parameter in `pyproject.toml` from `poetry`, also without any effect.

```
...
[tool.bandit]
targets = "my_package"
exclude = ".venv" # This line has no effect too
skips = "B101"
...
```

Even with all those attemps, the bandit still scan `.venv` folder.

Comment: what version of `bandit` do you have?

Comment: I'm using version `1.7.0` @lmiguelvargasf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is an issue of bandit that I found [here](https://github.com/PyCQA/bandit/issues/488). I think you should use the absolute path to `.venv` as follows:

```sh
poetry run bandit --exclude "./absolute/path/.venv"  -r .
```

Use the absolute path in the config file too:

```
[tool.bandit]
targets = "my_package"
exclude = "./absolute/path/.venv" #
```

Comment: we can also use relative path like `bandit -r . -x ./.venv`

Answer (score 0):

if you have defined the `.pre-commit-config.yaml` here is working sample to ignore multiple dirs:

```
-   repo: local
    hooks:
    -   id: bandit
        name: python-bandit-vulnerability-check
        entry: bandit
        args: [ '-r', '.', '-x', 'env, venv' ]
        language: system
        pass_filenames: false
```

Comment: If you do this via pre-commit, venv is excluded anyway, as it's not in the git index. So this answer is likely not helpful to anybody as is. Consider adding a note explaining that. This answer would be still useful for other files that **are** tracked by git, so no dv

Comment: though venv is not in the git index, in my case, I had to explicitly include `venv` because bandit is not excluding this directory otherwise.

Comment: `args: [ '-r', '.', '-x', './env', '-x', './venv' ]` is also a valid option.